# Theano with gpu. Using cuDNN version 5110 on context None

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

I'm trying to use Theano with gpu. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Firstly, typing `import theano` will result in

```
Using cuDNN version 5110 on context None
Mapped name None to device cuda0: GeForce GTX 1080 (0000:01:00.0)
```

To see if my GPU is being used I try [test from theano documentation](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-the-gpu)

My ~/.theanorc is

```
[global]
device = cuda0
floatX = float32

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
```

In this case test says:

```
[GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<GpuArrayType<None>(float32, (False,))>), 
HostFromGpu(gpuarray)(GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0)]
Looping 1000 times took 0.191431 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879349  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761 1.62323296]
Used the cpu
```

But using old backend with `device = gpu0` says:

```
[GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>), HostFromGpu(GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0)]
Looping 1000 times took 0.199280 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879349  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761 1.62323296]
Used the gpu
```

So I think something goes wrong with cuda. How can I check if its ok? Why "context" is "None"? Why does test say "using cpu" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to replace cuda0 with cuda.

I was having the same warning-like text after importing theano:

Using cuDNN version 5110 on context None
Mapped name None to device cuda: GeForce GT 750M (0000:01:00.0)

I went ahead and trained a DNN, I can see the speed is much faster than I ran my code on CPU before. So, I guess the text doesn't mean GPU is not working.